# Can I remove 'dash home' from the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

How can I (if it's possible), remove the dash home icon on the unity launcher. My reasoning is that it is slow (taking a few seconds to open) and I much prefer Synapse for launching applications and files.

There was an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/68502/176889) but that was for 12.04 and it no longer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is currently possible. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/80399/147044) by [Mark Shuttleworth](https://askubuntu.com/users/5287/mark-shuttleworth):

> In the desktop interface, the Dash icon and the Trash icon use the top and bottom slots of the launcher, **always**.

Comment: OK, I was thinking that there might be a new workaround, like with my linked question but I can understand Mark's reasoning

Comment: @minerz029 Maybe someday someone will find a hack to do this. I have not succeeded. So for now I trust [Mark Shuttleworth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth).