# Is there a way to replace Unity Dash with a classic style applications menu

Tags: unity, gnome, unity-dash, menu, globalmenu

Love this site, just joined because I finally figured out exactly how I want Ubuntu to behave and I haven't been able to find a way to do this.  I know there are things like the classic menu indicator, and I have mostly used cairo-dock because I like it's main menu, instead of Unity's dash, which I still can't stand.  I've messed around with all kinds of Ubuntu flavors and I really think in the end Ubunutu would be perfect with Unity, but with the dash system replaced.

Comment: Xfce sounds more up your alley.. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah I mainly just use ubuntu-studio (which is xfce) with all panels disabled and cairo-dock on the left side.  That's the best so far...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "classic style applications menu".. Could you clarify that?

Comment: Where you just click a menu button and all your programs are displayed and arranged by type (internet, games, media, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can always switch to the gnome desktop. Open a terminal and issue the following command.

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

Logout and then back in, choosing Gnome. (You'll have to click the Ubuntu symbol next to your user name on the login screen to access the options for Gnome Metacity and Gnome Compiz).

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that.  It's not really what I am looking for though.  The closest thing I can find is something called Cardapio, but it appears the ppa doesn't work anymore?  Anyone know how to get Cardapio if the ppa isn't working?
[link](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/cardapio-main-menu-alternative-launcher-for-ubuntu/)

Comment: @JoshuaDoomslangMcCormack The comment section is for comments, requesting clarification and such if you have a new question please use the ask question button at the upper right. I'm sorry my solution wasn't the one you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you can install Cardapio as following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cardapio
```

Comment: Thank you for this working ppa.  After installing Cardopia I downloaded the tar from a link on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xWHc-2Vjj0
and then followed the instructions to add it to the launcher.  Unfortunately I still can't figure out how to remove the unity dash icon from the launcher.

Comment: @JoshuaDoomslangMcCormack see that [Can I remove 'dash home' from the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339556/can-i-remove-dash-home-from-the-unity-launcher)