# Is it possible to move the dash home button?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

It's a problem for me because I keep hitting that button when I don't want to.  For example, I accidentally click it when I want to:

1. close a program
2. minimise a program
3. select a file on the desktop which is close to it

Its placement is quiet frustrating.  About 2 years of using it, and I still keep clicking it accidentally when I don't want to...

For example, Microsoft Windows moved the show desktop button to the other side so people  wouldn't accidentally click the start button when trying to click the show desktop button.  It's a similar situation.

Comment: I agree with you on this - Ubuntu seems to be getting as bad as Windows... For 12.04 the answer from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68502/how-can-i-remove-the-dash-home-icon-from-the-unity-launcher) should work, I am just wondering how to do this in 13.10...

Comment: Maybe pointing out the obvious: If you don't like design features in Ubuntu, try derivatives like Kubuntu or Xubuntu (my favorite).

Comment: Where exactly do you want to move it? At least in theory, it's possible to, e.g., swap the home and trash icon, but then you'd accidentally open the trash all the time...

Comment: First point of Ubuntu Philosophy = `Should have the freedom to download, run, copy, distribute, study, share, *change* and improve their software for any purpose, without paying licensing fees.`  Seems like Unity is part of Ubuntu, so you would think that you would be able to `change` basic features of Unity, like the placement of the launcher, top, bottom, left, or right.  I'm thinking the Ubuntu Philosophy needs to be updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. To confirm my short (and maybe unpleasant) answer, I will quote the answer given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/80399/147044) by [Mark Shuttleworth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth):

> In the desktop interface, **the Dash icon** and the Trash icon **use the top**
>   and bottom slots of the launcher, **always**.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to move the dash home button or the unity bar if you're using a release above 12.04. A possible work around would be to [autohide the unity bar](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/automatically-hide-unity-launcher-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) when not being clicked on and lower the sensitivity so it doesn't appear unless your mouse is very far left and [move the windows button to the right](http://handytutorial.com/move-window-buttons-to-right-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/), but maximized windows still show the buttons on the left.